# How can a stiffness of a spring can be $k(x+x^3)$? Compute energy total of the system

Tags: homework-and-exercises, energy, spring, anharmonic-oscillators

> Consider the motion of a particle of mass $m$ attached to a spring of stiffness $k(x+x^3)$ where $x$ is the displacement.

**1)** How can look such a spring? I thought that the stiffness of a spring where always something as $F=kx$.

The equation of the movement is given by $$m\ddot x+k(x+x^3)=0.$$

**2)** How can I get the total energy of the system ? The kinetic energy is $\frac{1}{2}m\dot x^2$, but for the potential energy, I don't know in this case. I would say $\frac{1}{2}kx^2$ if the equation would be $m\ddot x-kx=0$, but in this situation, I don't know.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stiffness  It might help you.

Comment: Elastic potential energy $=\int_0^x F\,dx$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The potential energy $U$ is equal to the work $W$ done when deforming the spring:

$$\mathrm{d}W=F\mathrm{d}x=[k(x+x^3)]\mathrm{d}x$$
$$\Rightarrow W=\int_0^x [k(x+x^3)]\mathrm{d}x$$
$$U=W=k(\frac12 x^2+\frac13 x^4)$$

> 1) How can look such a spring ? I thought that the stiffness of a
>   spring where always something as $F=kx$.

Yes, that's Hookean (linear) spring. The cubic case may have been created purely for the sake of this exercise.

For the general case of $F(x)=kf(x)$, then:

$$U=k\int_0^x f(x)\mathrm{d}x$$

Comment: "The cubic case may have been created purely for the sake of this exercise" - see my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

In the real world, springs are not linear. Some "springs" used in engineering are specially designed NOT to obey Hooke's law, for example [Belleville washers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Belleville_washer).

A nonlinear spring with stiffness $k(x + ax^3)$ (note, $a$ can be either positive or negative) is the simplest "toy" example of a nonlinear spring, and, conveniently, it can imitate the important features of the behaviour of real nonlinear springs.

The OP's equation is a simple special case of the [Duffing equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duffing_equation) for which the nonlinear behaviour has been (and still is being!) studied in great detail.